# PHP-FPM doesn't write on the log

Tags: php

I have this php-fpm.conf

```
[example.com]
        listen                 = 127.0.0.1:9001
        listen.owner           = example.com
        listen.group           = example.com
        listen.mode            = 0660
        listen.backlog         = -1

        user  = example.com
        group = example.com

        pm                   = dynamic
        pm.max_requests      = 0
        pm.max_children      = 2
        pm.start_servers     = 1
        pm.min_spare_servers = 1
        pm.max_spare_servers = 1

        chroot = /home/vhosts/example.com/

        request_terminate_timeout = 2
        request_slowlog_timeout   = 1
        slowlog                   = /home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-slow.log

        catch_workers_output = yes

        env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
        env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
        env[TMP] = /tmp
        env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
        env[TEMP] = /tmp


        php_flag[display_errors]            = on
        php_admin_value[session.save_path]  = /tmp
        php_admin_value[error_log]          = /home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-error.log
        php_admin_flag[log_errors]          = on
        php_admin_value[memory_limit]       = 100M
        php_value[max_execution_time]       = 20
```

I don't understand why /home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-error.log is empty, I caused some errors like 10 / 0 (Zero division) etc etc, I see the error as output but the php-error.log still empty.

I chrooted my vhost, but If i change

/home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-error.log

to

/log/php-error.log

I get a really strange error, when I do "10 / 0"!

```
Fatal error: main(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /web/index.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 3):

From Debian's documentation:

> ### Timezone data from system timezone database
>
> Debian PHP has been patched to use of the system wide timezone database
>   from the tzdata package, making sure any updates there are automatically
>   used by PHP aswell.
>
> Note that this requires that the PHP process has access to /etc/localtime
>   and /usr/share/zoneinfo. For any regular installation this should be the
>   case, but in specific secured environments when reading the timezone
>   database is impossible PHP will give a "Timezone database is corrupt -
>   this should *never* happen!" error.

So you need to copy /etc/localtime file and /usr/share/zoneinfo directory to your chroot directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the log entries because the log path you're specifying is the 'real path':

```
php_admin_value[error_log]          = /home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-error.log
```

Because you are chrooting you need to specify the 'chroot relative path':

```
php_admin_value[error_log]          = /log/php-error.log
```

This is because for the php-fpm worker /home/vhosts/example.com/ is really / due to the chrooting.

I haven't tested it but I suspect your session path might also be subject to this as well, so you'll need to make sure "chrooted /tmp" exists (really /home/vhosts/example.com/tmp) and is writable by the user you're using for that php-fpm pool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having similar issues that could be related to the listen.backlog setting.
I've been finding different posts claiming that -1 can be wrongly interpreted.  I'm currently experimenting with setting listen.backlog to 0 or a high value.  I'll see what the outcome is and keep you posted.

Have you tried correcting the log path as follows?
log/php-error.log (the leading slash makes it look for the /log folder which usually doesn't exist on a Linux system.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have SELinux active make sure you grant permission for writing the log. Example:

```bash
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/opt/remi/php73/log/php-fpm/
```